# mysql_num_rows return always zero when I use polish letters

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

so I have little problem, because I need to check if "product" exists in database, and if not, I want to create one. I was doing something like this:

```
$tekst2 = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE nazwa = '$nazwa'";
$id_zap2 = mysql_query($tekst2);
if(!$id_zap2)
{
    return new Response('Nie można przesłać zapytania.');
}
else
{
    $row2 = mysql_num_rows($id_zap2);
}

if($row2 == 0)      
{
    $product->setCena($cena);
    $product->setJednostka($jednostka);
    $product->setIlosc($ilosc);
    $product->setNazwa($nazwa);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();   

    return $this->redirect('addproduct?done=' . $nazwa);    
}   
else
{
    return $this->redirect('addproduct?error=1');   
}
```

And when I'm using for "$nazwa" normal letters all is ok. For example "Kukurydza", "Chleb" work fine, but when I use polish letters, for example "Mąka" it always returns 0 as "$row2" and I can create a lot of products with the same name ($nazwa).

Comment: Have you considered this could be a character set problem?

Comment: I tried "utf8_unicode_ci", "utf8_polish_ci" and "utf8_general_ci". Still don't work.

Comment: Where have you tried setting these? What is the character set/encoding the database is using? That should also be one you use in the application.

Comment: I tried change it in database (collation). I need to add something about character set in my php code?

Comment: ```ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; ```

```ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;``` - ***dont forget to back you'r db before***.

Comment: I'm no expert on PHP but yes your application itself will need to use some character set as well and the default one might not be the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I hade to add:

```
$tekst3 = "SET NAMES utf8";
mysql_query($tekst3);
$tekst3 = "SET CHARACTER_SET utf8_unicode_ci";
mysql_query($tekst3);
```

In my code and now all works ok!